# Caching does not work for Content Search Web-Parts

Tags: caching, sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-online

#### Background Information

Content Search Web-Parts supports a caching feature as described here: [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-pages-load-faster-with-caching-in-the-Content-Search-Web-Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-pages-load-faster-with-caching-in-the-Content-Search-Web-Part-1211e821-3559-4fbd-b157-853ac594d890?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).
This should bring enhanced performance.

#### Problem

When configuring caching as described in the article the Content Search Web-Part does not return any results.

#### Steps to reproduce

- Insert a Content Search Web-Part into a page
- Edit the query (for testing purposes here: Recently changed items)
- Under Settings activate the option caching for everyone except external users

After saving and publishing the Content Search Web-Part does not return any result. This is reproducable in multiple tenants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

If you want to enable caching for a security group, this security group requires permissions on the site collection (min. read permission).
In my case "Everyone, except external users" had no read permissions on the site collection.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer as this worked for me! Thank you for this discovery!